# Need specific mysql statement to get master word and all words in one select

Tags: mysql

I have a table like:

```
ID   word   masterWord
1    test   1
1    test1  0
1    test2  0
2    look   0
2    kiss   1
2    eye    0
```

Now I'd like to get from select statement 2 records with:

```
test      test1, test2
kiss      look, eye
```

First column is master word, second column in group_concat all the other words.

Master words are marked with true (1) in the table and the ID's are declaration which words holds a group (of synonyms). Ok, I know I've made stupid words but I am making this for non English language that has one word has different endings depending on it's count, gender etc...

Every ID MUST have one word selected as master word... if that helps query or not I don't know ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN masterWord = 1 THEN word END) AS masterWord ,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN masterWord = 0 THEN word END) AS OtherWords
FROM YourTable       
GROUP BY ID
```

Should do it. Perhaps you might need to add a `CAST` to the `GROUP_CONCAT` input as well.

Comment: You did it, it really works, only explain doesn't use my indexes, I wonder what must be indexed.

Comment: @Jerry2 there is no index to use, this is a full table scan (1-pass) since it will involve all your records

Comment: Well, of course... I am now making query that would select all the words except master word if the word is given (there I will need index). Here I don't. It is just using filesort that I don't like. BTW: Is there a way to modify your solution to sort the words (the master words and the synonyms for each master word)?

Comment: @Jerry - What if you add `ORDER BY word` to the [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Comment: @Martin - congratulations on 10K. I'm going to get told off but I looked at some of your older answers and they were all goood

Comment: @Richard - Ha ha! Thanks - Lets see if they survive the daily voting anomaly checker!

Comment: If I put "order by word asc" at the end it works, but uses temporary and filesort :-( I gave index to ID, masterword, but doesn't help. Any idea maybe?

Comment: You have 10k and 12k and I have... 83 ;-(

Comment: @Martin how can I add order by to group concat, I can only add to the end after group by... I am a newbie it seems in mysql and I thought I was quite good :-(

Comment: @Jerry - Execution Plans in MySQL isn't something I know that much about. I guess you could try a composite index on `ID,masterWord,word` and on `ID,word,masterWord` to see if you can get rid of the sort with either of those. Edit: And if you click through to the link above for the `group_concat` documentation it shows you the syntax for `order by` it goes inside the `group_concat()` statement itself.

Comment: If I put order by after group_by nothing get's rid of temporary.

Comment: @Jerry - In other RDBMSs it would be invalid syntax to reference a non aggregated column that you aren't grouping by. I don't think you can rely on it returning the details for the correct row without putting it in an aggregate.

Comment: @Martin: Sorry I didn't see the link. Thanx for the explanation about MAX. I still have a lot to learn.

Comment: @Marin: You are "not good" in indexes yes ;-)))... Putting order by word on concat did help explain "using index" :-) And my synonyms words are now sorted. But putting order by on the end to sort the masterwords for the table produces temporary table. Unfortunately I can not use the order by on the "max" in select like I did on concat.

Comment: @Jerry - That's inevitable isn't it? You need the input to be sorted by `id` so that the `group by` doesn't entail an intermediate sort but you want the output to be sorted by word...

Comment: @Marin - I guess you are right about the using filesort, as the output must be filesorted at the end using masterword (the MAX part), but I would like to get rid of using temporary...

Answer (score 2):

```
select m.word, group_concat(w.word) wordlist
from words m
left join words w on w.masterword=0 and w.id=m.id
where m.masterword=1
group by m.id
```

Comment: This also works good. I don't know who's answer to choose now, you are both great :-(

Comment: Martin's is most likely faster, in fact, about 99.9% sure

Comment: Thanx for the honesty. I will accept his answer then, but yours is vers usefull also, it made me learn something. Thanx